# Connect to Windows share from Red Hat machine via DNS name

Tags: rhel, samba

We have a Windows share `\\server1\share`

From a Red Hat machine, we can mount to the share without issue.

We have setup a DNS pointer that points to `server1` and is named `production`.

From the Linux machine, we are able to ping `production` and we get the corresponding DNS address from `server1` but we are unable to mount the share via the name `\\production\share`.

Anyone ever dealt with this?

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Is the typo `\\prodution\share` only in your question, or in your actual tests as well?

Comment: I had the same problem. The solution was to create a domain on my dns( `.company.lan`) create an A record to the hostname the same way you already did, and on your dhcp deliver the `.company.lan` suffix. Windows will not resolv names without a domain. If you set up fixed ip address to windows, you will also have to configure this domain manually -  http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a138/how-to-configure-dns-suffixes-on-windows-vista-2008.aspx . After doing this you will be able to access `production` and `production.company.lan` . `.lan` Top level domain can be user as internal domain.

Comment: After that, add the `search company.lan` parameter to you `resolv.conf`  on Linux

Answer (score 0):

For future refference, the problem lay on the windows side. You must edit this key to get it to work:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\

DisableStrictNameChecking[REG_DWORD#32] = 1

Reboot and wahlah.